# gatsby-node.js createPages is not sending data to component in pageContext

Tags: gatsby, netlify

You can see I'm logging the data returned from my lambda function. The data is **definitely** coming back as expected. However, in the createPage(...), the allMessages in pageContext in the dashboard.js component is always null/undefined.

Why?...

**dashboard.js**

```
const DashboardPage = ({ pageContext: { allMessages } }) => (
    <Layout>
        <SEO title="Dashboard" keywords={[`gatsby`, `application`, `react`]} />
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
        {console.log('allMessages: ', allMessages)}
        {allMessages.map(mssg => (
            <li
                key={mssg.id}
                style={{
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    listStyle: 'none',
                    display: 'inline-block'
                }}
            >
                <Link to={`/message/${mssg.name}`}>
                    <p>{mssg.name}</p>
                </Link>
            </li>
        ))}
    </Layout>
);

export default DashboardPage;
```

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createPage } }) => {
    get('get-messages')
        .then(allMessages => {
            console.log('gatsby-node allMessages: ', allMessages);
            // Create a page that lists all Pokémon.
            createPage({
                path: `/dashoard`,
                component: require.resolve('./src/pages/dashboard.js'),
                context: { allMessages }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return Promise.reject(new Error(err));
        });
};
```

I'm blocked. Thank you for sharing your expertise!

**EDIT:**

This doesn't work either. Same undefined in dashboard.js...

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createPage } }) => {
    get('get-messages')
        .then(allMessages => {
            // allMessages = typeof allMessages === 'string' ? JSON.parse(allMessages) : allMessages;
            // console.log('gatsby-node allMessages: ', allMessages);
            // // Create a page that lists all Pokémon.
            const test = [{ name: 'Test message' }];
            createPage({
                path: `/dashoard`,
                component: require.resolve('./src/pages/dashboard.js'),
                context: { allMessages: test }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return Promise.reject(new Error(err));
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The context data you're passing in CreatePages is already accessible in your DashboardPage component as a prop.
Instead of trying to take it into your DashboardPage component as a parameter, try accessing the allMessages data directly with `this.props.pageContext`.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because js page components must be in a **template** directory and not in the same folder with MarkDown files:

```
require.resolve('./src/pages/templates/dashboard.js'),
```