# TypeError cannot read property undefined - Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I'm stuck with this problem and I'm not sure what's wrong. I am new to Gatsby.

I am trying to create pages from a JSON file. I keep getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Layout' of undefined

Here's the JSON data and code:

**JSON file**

```
{
    "Header" : {
        "TopMenu" : [
            {
                "url" : "/log-in",
                "name" : "Log in",
                "target" : "_self"
            },
            {
                "url" : "/about",
                "name" : "About",
                "target" : "_self"
            }
        ],
        "MainMenu" : [
            {
                "url" : "/",
                "name" : "Home",
                "target" : "_self"
            },
            {
                "url" : "/service",
                "name" : "Service",
                "target" : "_self"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Footer" : {
        "Links" : [
            {
                "url" : "/",
                "name" : "Home",
                "target" : "_self"
            },
            {
                "url" : "/service",
                "name" : "Service",
                "target" : "_self"
            },
            {
                "url" : "/blog",
                "name" : "Blog",
                "target" : "_self"
            }
        ]
    },
    "pages" : [
        {
            "name" : "Home",
            "content" : "This is the home page.",
            "url" : "/"
        },
        {
            "name" : "About",
            "content" : "This is the about page.",
            "url" : "/about"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Service",
            "content" : "This is the service page.",
            "url" : "/service"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Blog",
            "content" : "This is the blog page.",
            "url" : "/blog"
        }
    ]
}
```

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.createPages = ({actions}) => {
    const {createPage} = actions
    const pageData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./content/data.json', { encoding: 'utf-8' }));
    const pageTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/page.js');

    pageData.pages.forEach(page => {
        createPage({
          path: page.url,
          component: pageTemplate,
          context: {
            Layout : {
                Header : pageData.Header,
                Footer : pageData.Footer
            },
            ...page,
          }
        });
      });
}
```

**src/template/page.js**

```
import React from "react"
 const Page = props => {
    const { Layout = null, name = null, content = null, url = null } = props.PageContext;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <MainLayout headerLayout={Layout.Header} footerLayout={Layout.Footer}>
            {content}
        </MainLayout>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

export default Page;
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        //icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:**
Added the gatsby-config.js

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please add `gatsby-config.js`

Comment: Hi @ksav I have added the gatsby-config. Seems like i'm also having the same problem with Locohost in his post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990208/gatsby-node-js-createpages-is-not-sending-data-to-component-in-pagecontext#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a typo there. In `src/template/page.js`, it should be `props.pageContext` instead of `props.PageContext`. `PageContext` is undefined, hence the type error.

```
    const {
      Layout = null,
      name = null
      content = null,
      url = null 
-   } = props.PageContext;
+   } = props.pageContext;
```